# Rails3 Autocomplete - Object has no method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement autocomplete feature. I've looked through https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete but I had to missed something because autocomplete field simply doesnt work.

When I'm trying to use autocomplete field nothing happens. Chrome JS console displays following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'
```

## Controller:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :game, :title
```

## routes.rb:

```
get "games/autocomplete_game_title" => "games#autocomplete_game_title", :controller => 'games', :action => "autocomplete_game_title", :via => :get, :as => "autogames"
```

## View *(games/edit)*:

```
<% form_for Game.new, :url => { :controller => "games", :action => "edit" } do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_messages %>
 <%= f.autocomplete_field :title, autogames_path %>
 <%= f.submit "Edit" %>
<%  end %>
```

## Layout header:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/admin.css?1300378198" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1335792905" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1335792905" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1335809045" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/autocomplete-rails.js?1336304504" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am completely confused, I've checked almost all combinations. Any suggestions what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into many issues trying to use that gem with Rails > 3.0, I ended up using a straight Jquery-UI alternative, which is also easier. You might want to check out this [link](http://babinho.net/2011/05/autocomplete-fields-in-rails-3-1-with-jquery-ui-pt-2/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your not loading jquery-ui, you need to add the js and css require if using asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and resolved, then posted some comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705158/rails3-jquery-autocomplete). You may want to check out.