# Using jquery-autocomplete-rails , unable to show autocomplete list to select from

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery-autocomplete-rails to try to dynamically populate a drop-down list of existing cabinets to select when a user is creating a new device.  I wish to display cabinet.names but capture cabinet.id of the selected item for the form.

The form tag:

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'cabinet', '', cabinets_autocomplete_cabinet_name_path %>
    <% f.hidden_field :cabinet_id, :id => "real cabinet id" %>
```

The beginning of the devices and cabinets controllers:

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
autocomplete :device, :cabinet, :name
...
end

class CabinetsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :cabinet, :name
...
end
```

Associated routes from routes.rb:

```
get 'devices/autocomplete_cabinet_name'
get 'cabinets/autocomplete_cabinet_name'
```

It looks like the command is not failing, but when I begin typing in the form (0055 in this instance), the following is displayed to the console:

```
Started GET "/cabinets/autocomplete_cabinet_name?term=0055-" for 127.0.0.1 at 20
13-04-03 10:45:08 -0400
Processing by CabinetsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"0055-", "id"=>"autocomplete_cabinet_name"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users
`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCabinet Load (5.9ms)←[0m  SELECT `cabinets`.* FROM `cabinets` WHERE (
name LIKE '%0055-%')
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)
```

The user query has to do with my login I guess.

I've used the following resources for help already:
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app
Many corrections to the previous tutorial are here:
[rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705158/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)

Please provide help if you can.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a jquery package installed with no themes.  Therefore nothing was being displayed.